# SET IDENTITY_INSERT not working on specific account

Tags: sql-server

I have an Admin_Acct which is the DB_Owner where I have grant User_Acct a Write Permission to a table SrcTable_Arc. I have this query:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT SrcTable_Arc ON
     INSERT INTO SrcTable_Arc (
        TxnDate
        ,TxnName
        ,ServerName
        ,ReplyReceived
        ,HistoryId)
    SELECT 
        TxnDate
        ,TxnName
        ,ServerName
        ,ReplyReceived
        ,HistoryId
    FROM SrcTable
    WHERE TxnDate = '2019-11-08 10:06:09.888'
    ORDER BY TxnDate Desc
     SET IDENTITY_INSERT SrcTable_Arc OFF
```

This query works when I use the Admin_Acct.
But, when I try to run this query using user_Acct, it gives an error:

> Msg 1088, Level 16, State 11, Line 3
>   Cannot find the object "SrcTable_Arc" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

I have checked the permissions of this account to this table and it has the permissions already.

Anyway, when I do simple Update, Insert and Delete to that table using User_Admin acct, it works.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the user account doesn't have necessary permissions on the `SrcTable_Arc` table for the `identity_insert`. Documentation [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql) it clearly that:

> Permissions
>
> User must own the table or have ALTER permission on the table.

Personally, I wouldn't recommend granting this kind of permission directly to the user. Instead, wrap your code into a stored procedure and make sure that procedure's schema owner does have all the necessary permissions, then grant the `execute` on that procedure to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You could try turning on identity_insert prior to the insert command?

> SET IDENTITY_INSERT SrcTable_Arc ON

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT SrcTable_Arc ON     
INSERT INTO SrcTable_Arc (
            TxnDate
            ,TxnName
            ,ServerName
            ,ReplyReceived
            ,HistoryId)
        SELECT 
            TxnDate
            ,TxnName
            ,ServerName
            ,ReplyReceived
            ,HistoryId
        FROM SrcTable
        WHERE TxnDate = '2019-11-08 10:06:09.888'
        ORDER BY TxnDate Desc
         SET IDENTITY_INSERT SrcTable_Arc OFF
```